Sqlalchemy postgresql Reserved key word as column name not able to insert
I have a table with column name "collation" whose schema I cannot change.
I generated some data I want to insert into this table using the following code snippet:
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

metadata = MetaData(schema=self.schema_name)
metadata.reflect(bind=self.engine)

# Get the list of tables in the schema
tables = metadata.sorted_tables
table = list(tables)[0]
data = [{"collation": "foo"}, {"collation":"bar"}]
stmt = postgresql.insert(table).values(data)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(stmt.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
    conn.commit()

I get the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "collation"
LINE 1: ... (id, column_name, common_data_type, default_val, collation,...
                                                             ^


I have tried replacing the column name with quoted_string("collation",True) but I still get the same error.
How can I get sqlalchemy to generate the insert query with quotes around the column collation?

As shown in Ian Wilson's answer, you need to set quote=True on the column to ensure that it is quoted correctly, but the tricky part here is that you are reflecting an existing table. You need to override the column definition in SQLAlchemy to introduce quote=True.  For a single table, you could do it like this:
tbl = sa.Table(
    't', 
    sa.MetaData(), 
    sa.Column('collation', sa.String, quote=True), 
    autoload_with=engine
)

If the table is already in a metadata object, you can override using extend_existing:
tbl = sa.Table(
    't', 
    metadata, 
    sa.Column('collation', sa.String, quote=True), 
    extend_existing=True
)

Here's a complete example for the existing metadata case:
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', echo=True)

DROP = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t78486844"""
CREATE = """CREATE TABLE t78486844 ("collation" varchar)"""
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test', echo=True)

DROP = """DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t78486844"""
CREATE = """CREATE TABLE t78486844 ("collation" varchar)"""

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.text(DROP))
    conn.execute(sa.text(CREATE))

metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['t78486844'])
tbl = metadata.tables['t78486844']
# Override the definition in the metadata.
tbl = sa.Table(
    't78486844',
    metadata,
    sa.Column('collation', sa.String, quote=True),
    extend_existing=True,
)

# "Standard" insert.
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert(), [{'collation': c} for c in ['foo', 'bar']])

# Insert from the question.
data = [{'collation': 'foo'}, {'collation': 'bar'}]
stmt = postgresql.insert(tbl).values(data)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(stmt.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
    conn.commit()

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(sa.text(DROP))
    conn.execute(sa.text(CREATE))

metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['t78486844'])
tbl = metadata.tables['t78486844']
tbl = sa.Table(
    't78486844',
    metadata,
    sa.Column('collation', sa.String, quote=True),
    extend_existing=True,
)

with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(tbl.insert(), [{'collation': c} for c in ['foo', 'bar']])

data = [{'collation': 'foo'}, {'collation': 'bar'}]
stmt = postgresql.insert(tbl).values(data)
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(stmt.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
    conn.commit()


Passing quote=True to Column() seems to work.  I'm not sure where your schema is coming from but it seems to work for the ORM class and also with a Table() definition.
I tested this at least with:

sqlalchemy == 2.0.30
psycopg2 == 2.9.9 OR psycopg == 3.1.19
postgresql == 15.5

import os

from sqlalchemy import (
    Column,
    String,
    BigInteger,
    create_engine,
    Table,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import (
    select,
    insert,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import (
    declarative_base,
    Session,
)


def get_engine(env):
    return create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{env['DB_USER']}:{env['DB_PASSWORD']}@{env['DB_HOST']}:{env['DB_PORT']}/{env['DB_NAME']}", echo=True)

Base = declarative_base()

class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'samples'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    collation = Column(name="collation", type_=String, nullable=False, quote=True)


texts_t = Table(
    "texts",
    Base.metadata,
    Column('id', BigInteger, primary_key=True),
    Column('collation', type_=String, nullable=False, quote=True)
)

def main():
    engine = get_engine(os.environ)

    with engine.begin() as conn:
        Base.metadata.create_all(conn)

        populate(conn)

        query(conn)

    pop2(engine)


def query(conn):
    with Session(conn) as session:
        for sample in session.scalars(select(Sample)):
            print ('SAMPLE', sample.id, sample.collation)
        for row in session.execute(select(texts_t)):
            print ('TEXT', row[0], row[1])


def populate(conn):
    with Session(conn) as session:
        session.add(Sample(collation='en_us_ca_morro_bay'))
        session.add(Sample(collation='en_us_ca_santa_margarita'))
        session.execute(insert(texts_t).values([{"collation": "en_us_ca_morro_bay_1"}, {"collation": "en_us_ca_santa_margarita_1"}]))
        session.commit()

def pop2(engine):
    with engine.connect() as conn:
        conn.execute(insert(texts_t).values([{"collation": "en_us_ca_morro_bay_3"}, {"collation": "en_us_ca_santa_margarita_4"}]))
        conn.commit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


Echo Output
2024-05-16 23:19:48,858 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select pg_catalog.version()
2024-05-16 23:19:48,858 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,859 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select current_schema()
2024-05-16 23:19:48,859 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,859 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
2024-05-16 23:19:48,859 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,870 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-05-16 23:19:48,873 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT pg_catalog.pg_class.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class JOIOutoutN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid = pg_catalog.pg_class.relnamespace 
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_class.relname = %(table_name)s AND pg_catalog.pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY[%(param_1)s, %(param_2)s, %(param_3)s, %(param_4)s, %(param_5)s]) AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AND pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname != %(nspname_1)s
2024-05-16 23:19:48,873 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00019s] {'table_name': 'samples', 'param_1': 'r', 'param_2': 'p', 'param_3': 'f', 'param_4': 'v', 'param_5': 'm', 'nspname_1': 'pg_catalog'}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,874 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT pg_catalog.pg_class.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid = pg_catalog.pg_class.relnamespace 
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_class.relname = %(table_name)s AND pg_catalog.pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY[%(param_1)s, %(param_2)s, %(param_3)s, %(param_4)s, %(param_5)s]) AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AND pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname != %(nspname_1)s
2024-05-16 23:19:48,875 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.001893s ago] {'table_name': 'texts', 'param_1': 'r', 'param_2': 'p', 'param_3': 'f', 'param_4': 'v', 'param_5': 'm', 'nspname_1': 'pg_catalog'}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,875 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE samples (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, 
    "collation" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2024-05-16 23:19:48,875 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00007s] {}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,884 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine 
CREATE TABLE texts (
    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL, 
    "collation" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2024-05-16 23:19:48,884 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00008s] {}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,891 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO texts ("collation") VALUES (%(collation_m0)s), (%(collation_m1)s)
2024-05-16 23:19:48,891 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00013s] {'collation_m0': 'en_us_ca_morro_bay_1', 'collation_m1': 'en_us_ca_santa_margarita_1'}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,892 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO samples ("collation") SELECT p0::VARCHAR FROM (VALUES (%(collation__0)s, 0), (%(collation__1)s, 1)) AS imp_sen(p0, sen_counter) ORDER BY sen_counter RETURNING samples.id, samples.id AS id__1
2024-05-16 23:19:48,892 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00004s (insertmanyvalues) 1/1 (ordered)] {'collation__0': 'en_us_ca_morro_bay', 'collation__1': 'en_us_ca_santa_margarita'}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,894 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT samples.id, samples."collation" 
FROM samples
2024-05-16 23:19:48,894 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00007s] {}
SAMPLE 1 en_us_ca_morro_bay
SAMPLE 2 en_us_ca_santa_margarita
2024-05-16 23:19:48,894 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT texts.id, texts."collation" 
FROM texts
2024-05-16 23:19:48,894 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00006s] {}
TEXT 1 en_us_ca_morro_bay_1
TEXT 2 en_us_ca_santa_margarita_1
2024-05-16 23:19:48,894 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2024-05-16 23:19:48,896 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-05-16 23:19:48,896 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO texts ("collation") VALUES (%(collation_m0)s), (%(collation_m1)s)
2024-05-16 23:19:48,896 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00010s] {'collation_m0': 'en_us_ca_morro_bay_3', 'collation_m1': 'en_us_ca_santa_margarita_4'}
2024-05-16 23:19:48,896 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT



Thanks for your answer, I have quote=True:
Table(...).append_column(Column(name='collation',quote=True))

Did you try using execute as I did instead of manually compiling the statement?

No luck! I went with manually constructing the insert statements

That is weird because it is working for me.  Maybe because I'm using the new driver. What version of SQL alchemy are you using?

sqlalchemy==2.0.29 and psycopg2==2.9.9

Still seems to work.  You are not calling compile() right ?  Like in your example code you call that and I think that just converts everything to a string before executing it instead of letting the driver do it.

I'm using postgresql 15.5, updated in answer, not sure what is going on here but there should be some way to make it work.

This approach, manually constructing the queries works, know that you quote all columns in the insert statement not just keywords.
data = [{"collation": "foo"}, {"collation":"bar"}]

columns_str = ', '.join(['"'+column.name+'"' for column in columns])
placeholders_str = ', '.join([':' + column.name for column in columns])
insert_statement = text(f'INSERT INTO  {self.schema_name}."{table.name}" ({columns_str}) VALUES ({placeholders_str})')

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute(insert_statement)
    conn.commit()

